# Unity - convert float to long

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I convert `float` to `long` :

```
float speed = 6.1f;
long longspeed = Convert.ToInt64(speed);
```

I will get `9.1552734375e-05`. Why is that?

Comment: It shouldn't ... and it can't. `9.1552734375e-05` is not a value you can store in a `long`.

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible, long can't store a decimal number:

```
float speed = 6.1f;
long longspeed = Convert.ToInt64(speed); // 6;
```

`Convert.ToInt64` converts the number to `long`, even if you store the result in a `float` variable, you get `6`.

You may try to Rebuild your solution, maybe an older version of the code is executing.